# Select all in current view in Filemaker Pro 12

Tags: database, filemaker

I have a Filemaker Pro 12 database that I can sort and export selections using check boxes, I have a script to "Select none" and remove all the ticked items, but I would like to be able to search and then check all the results.

I have a button on the checkbox image that performs a Set field and the following:

```
Case (
 ValueCount ( FilterValues ( Table::Checkbox ; Table::ID ) ) > 0;
 Substitute ( Table::Checkbox ; Table::ID & ¶ ; "" ) ;
 Table::Checkbox & Table::ID & ¶
```

)

Conditional formatting of the checkbox is:

```
not ValueCount ( FilterValues ( Table::Checkbox ; Table::ID ) ) > 0
```

The script for "Select none" is:

```
Set Field [Table::Checkbox; ""]
```

So what would the "Select all" script need to be?

Comment: A couple of questions, is `Table::Checkbox` where you're compiling all of the IDs a global field? Also, are you viewing the records in list view or via a portal?

Comment: Yes it's a global field and I'm viewing the records in list mode, not a portal.

Comment: Do you mean you want to **create a found set** containing all (and only) the records whose ID value is in the global checkbox field? Or the opposite: set the global Checkbox field to the IDs of the current found set?

Comment: It's the opposite, I already have a script to find all checked, just need to check all.

Comment: I have posted another option for you to explore. However, I wonder **why** you need this, since the storage in a global field is temporal anyway. "*For example I search for 9V batteries, run Check all, then search for 12V batteries, run Check all, then run Show checked and I should have a found set of both batteries*" Wouldn't it be simpler to *extend the found set* when searching for 12V batteries?

Comment: I am working with a database of equipment for hire. I can search for 9V batteries and then tick the items going out (e.g. all of them) and then do the same for 12V batteries, and then other individual items can be added. I then export a list, and can then make another. I'm sure there are other methods but for the moment this works for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few methods to collect values across a found set into a return-delimited list. Looping is fine if your found set is fairly small; otherwise it may prove too slow.

Since your target is a global field anyway, you could use a simple:

```
Replace Field Contents [ No dialog; Table::gCheckbox; List ( Table::gCheckbox ; Table::ID ) ]
```

This will append the current found-set's values to the existing list. To start anew, begin your script by:

```
Set Field [ Table::gCheckbox; "" ]
```

**Note:**
In version 13, you can use the new summary field option of "List".

**Caveat:**
Make sure you have a backup while you experiment with `Replace Field Contents[]`; there is no undo.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this was an even better solution! Works just how it should and is very fast. Sorry Chris your solution was good too but unfortunately wasn't additive.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script to walk through the current found set and get all of the IDs:

```
Set Variable [$currentRecord ; Get(RecordNumber)]
#
Goto Record [First]
Loop
Set Variable [$ids ; Table::ID & ¶ & $ids ]
Go To Record [Next ; Exit after Last]
End Loop
#
Go To Record [By Calculation ; $currentRecord]
# 
Set Field [Table::Checkbox ; $ids ]
```

This method would save your current position, walk through the current found set, compile the ids into a variable, return you to your position, and set the checkbox field.

Comment: I adjusted the Set Variable step for compiling the IDs, you'd want the new `Table::ID` on top of the existing `$ids`, that way when you create the first one you'll still have the format `###¶` that you use in your other code, i.e. making sure there's a carriage return after the ID number.

Comment: "*Go To Record [By Calculation ; $currentRecord]*" What exactly is the purpose of this step in your script?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I put that in so that once the script is done walking the current found set it returns the user to the record they started from. If the current active record is in the middle of the list I wouldn't want the user to be taken to the last record just from clicking a checkbox. Sometimes I'll open a separate window and hide it off screen before the record walk and then close the temp window so that I don't disturb the found set in the original window, but I thought that a bit more complicated than it needed to be to answer the question.

Comment: "*it returns the user to the record they started from.*" I am afraid you are very much mistaken about that. You probably meant storing the value of Get (RecordNumber); *that* would get you back (provided that the found set and sort order haven't changed, of course).

Comment: Ah, you're correct. I was thinking of the wrong record identifier.

Comment: This is great and works fine on a one use basis, but can it be additive? For example I search for 9V batteries, run Check all, then search for 12V batteries, run Check all, then run Show checked and I should have a found set of both batteries.

Comment: If you want it to include previously selected values you could start the script with the step `Set variable [ $ids ; Table::Checkbox ]`. That way your ids variable is pre-loaded with the previous selection.